# I need to dynamically import javascript file in angular 6 based on the window.MediaRecorder

Tags: angular, dynamic, import, conditional-statements

1.can anyone post a correct way to achieve this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
if (!window['MediaRecorder']) {
 import * as MediaRecorder from 'audio-recorder-polyfill';
 } else {
declare var MediaRecorder: any;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Es6 Dynamic import

> The import keyword may be called as a function to dynamically import a
>   module. When used this way, it returns a promise

```
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
  });
```

Ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

Ref:https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i am still getting error when i use this in angular 6